# JQuery: Chaining vs Callback Functions

Tags: jquery, callback, chaining

Below is the code snippet of JQuery code for Chaining vs Callback Function:-

```
$(selector).animate({ opacity: 1 }).animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

vs

```
$(selector).animate({ opacity: 1}, function()
{
    $(this).animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
```

In what type(s) of situation would  one want to prefer one over the other?

Comment: Just as a quick assessment, I would think that the first one would be more efficient since you don't have to cast $(this) as a jQuery object and then call animate on it. You probably only want to use the second option if you have to do more complicated stuff. Edit: I see you're not looking for efficiency, I would think both function the same though since in the first case, animate would have to return before the second call is run.

Comment: jQuery manage animations by queuing them so the second animation will still not be executed until the first one has finished. This only applies to animations though. See the example at http://api.jquery.com/queue/

Comment: @Stefan Makes sense. Would what you say apply to anything listed here? [jQuery Effects](http://api.jquery.com/category/effects/)

Comment: @technoTarek: Mostly. Some, like `.hide()` and `.show()` are able to operate optionally as an animation. So if you give those methods a duration, like `.hide(1000)`, then it will be queued. If no duration, then it isn't queued.

Comment: @amnotiam What about a duration of 0, such as `show(0)`? Would that be queued? Many thanks.

Comment: @technoTarek: Yep, that'll be sufficient to add it to the queue. It's a useful hack to chain `show/hide` after an animation.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

They are effectively the same, so you'd probably just use the first.

Callbacks (the second version) are for running any arbitrary code that isn't automatically queued.

This includes other jQuery methods like `.css()` for example, which if not in the callback, will run long before the animation is complete.

```
// .animate() is automatically queued
$(selector).animate({ opacity: 1 }).animate({ opacity: 0.5 });
```

---

```
// .css() is not automatically queued, so you'd need a callback
$(selector).animate({ opacity: 1 }, function() {
    $(this).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
});
```

---

Without the callback...

```
 // Animation starts ----v
$(selector).animate({ opacity: 1 }).css({ opacity: 0.5 });
 // ...but .css() runs immediately-------------^
 // ...because it isn't automatically added to the queue.
```

Comment: Good explanation, was just looking at the jQuery source and you are correct sir!

Answer (score 0):

The only difference is timing: The callback in the second example will not be executed until the first animate completes. The chained animate in the first example will happen immediately after the first animation begins.

Comment: @Rory I initially thought the timing differed too, but then I read this on jQuery.com:

Every element can have one to many queues of functions attached to it by jQuery. In most applications, only one queue (called fx) is used. Queues allow a sequence of actions to be called on an element asynchronously, without halting program execution... For example:

`$('#foo').slideUp().fadeIn();`

When this statement is executed, the element begins its sliding animation immediately, but the fading transition is placed on the fx queue to be called only once the sliding transition is complete.

Comment: @technoTarek this is very interesting, do you have a link for the lazy people (like myself)?