# jQuery chaining vs. callbacks for animation functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation

Say I have some element I want to animate:

```
$('.hey').show(1000).slideUp(1000);
```

What's the difference between this and:

```
$('.hey').show(1000, function() {
  $(this).slideUp(1000);
});
```

in terms of what happens internally? As far as I know, animations are asynchronous in jQuery. So the first example, `show` and `slideUp` should fire at the same time. In the second, `slideUp` should fire only after `show` ends.

Yet, for some reason, people like [on this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9314286/1085998) say they're the "same". Why are they same despite the (obvious) fact they work different (in the first example, the return will happen immediately, unlike with the second one)?

Comment: In JavaScript, under any circumstances, return will be immediate(`Excuse infinite while loops`)

Comment: @Satpal `show(duration)` uses fx queue too, just not `show()` without any parameter passed because anyway it is sync

Answer (score 5):

> Yet, for some reason, people like on this answer say they're the "same".

You're right, they aren't. There's a particularly large difference between them if more than one element matches `.hey`. But with your quoted code, although the sequence of steps they take is different, they end up *doing* much the same thing.

> Why are they same despite the (obvious) fact they work different (in the first example, the return will happen immediately, unlike with the second one)?

In both of those examples, the code runs and completes ("returns") immediately.

In the first example, the call to `slideUp` happens immediately *but* jQuery handles that call by adding the slideUp animation to the end of the animation queue and returning; the actual slideUp happens later, when reached in the animation queue.

In the second example, the call to `show` happens immediately and then, later when the animation is complete, the call to `slideUp` is done.

The key difference when multiple elements match your selector is that in your first example, there is **one** call to `slideUp`, which adds the slideUp operation to the animation queue for the current set of elements in the jQuery object you called it on. In the *second*, there are **multiple** calls to the completion callback, one for each element as it completes.

Another very important difference was highlighted by [Arun P Johny](https://stackoverflow.com/users/114251/arun-p-johny) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35037253/jquery-chaining-vs-callbacks-for-animation-functions/35037535?noredirect=1#comment57799554_35037535): If you were to add *another* animation function to those same elements later, with the first example it would be added to the queue *after* the `slideUp`, but in the second example the `slideUp` would be *after* that other animation.

But with your quoted code, again, while they take different roads to get there, they end up doing much the same thing.

Comment: I think there is another difference which is assume there is another event handler which gets executed while the show animation is running and it adds another animation now the order of animation changes in both cases... in first case the new animation will happen after slide up, but in second it will happen before - was just adding it as an answer